# Show/hide a column based on a selection from another column

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, conditional

I'm trying to format my SharePoint form to show/hide a column based on a selection from another column. If 'Other' is chosen from a column named 'Communication support', I'd like a free text column 'Other (please specify)' to appear.

I tried this simple Microsoft guidance (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/list-form-conditional-show-hide) to produce this:

```
=if([$Communication support] == 'Other', 'true', 'false')
```

As a result my 'Other (please specify)' column disappears but doesn't appear when 'Other' is selected under Communication support.

This might be a very simple questions for you, I'm only a beginner in SharePoint formatting.

Many thanks for your advice!

Comment: Try using correct **internal name** of "Communication support" column in formula. Follow [this article](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html) to find out the internal name of column in SharePoint. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Ganesh! Sorry for the late response, I have only just managed to test your suggestion. I have tried using internal name but it still didn't work. The 'Other column' disappeared from the form but would not appear when the 'Other' option was selected from the list.